# How to simplify Logic Gate - mux simulation

Tags: logic, cpu-architecture

When trying to make an multiplexor how do you go from this:

```
 Not(in=a, out=nota);
    Not(in=b, out=notb);
    Not(in=sel, out=notsel);
    And(a=a, b=b, out=aAndb);
    And(a=a, b=notb, out=aAndNotb);
    And(a=nota, b=b, out=bAndNota);
    And(a=aAndb, b=sel, out=aAndBAndSel);
    And(a=aAndb, b=notsel, out=aAndBAndNotSel);
    And(a=aAndNotb, b=notsel, out=aAndNotBAndNotSel);
    And(a=bAndNota, b=sel, out=bAndNotaAndSel);
    Or(a=aAndBAndSel, b=aAndBAndNotSel, out=o1);
    Or(a=o1, b=aAndNotBAndNotSel, out=o2);
    Or(a=o2, b=bAndNotaAndSel, out=out);
```

to this:

```
    Nand(a=sel, b=sel, out=notsel);
    Nand(a=a, b=notsel, out=asel);
    Nand(a=b, b=sel, out=bnotsel);
    Nand(a=asel, b=bnotsel, out=out);
```

my answer are always very long and i'm not sure how you would go about finding a more elegant solution.

```
MUX Truth Table Answers
|   a   |   b   |  sel  |  out  |
|   0   |   0   |   0   |   0   |
|   0   |   0   |   1   |   0   |
|   0   |   1   |   0   |   0   |
|   0   |   1   |   1   |   1   |
|   1   |   0   |   0   |   1   |
|   1   |   0   |   1   |   0   |
|   1   |   1   |   0   |   1   |
|   1   |   1   |   1   |   1   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Write down the truth table of the expression you have, use Karnaugh map to minimize it, then use boolean algebra to get the second expression. (By adding double not and applying de morgan law)

Answer (score 1):

That simplifies to:

```
BS + AS'
```

Or to use different notation:

```
(B & S) ∨ (A & ~S)
```